# Pushing Test Names to Sauce Labs with CodeceptJS

Tags: selenium, webdriver-io, saucelabs, codeceptjs

I have been trying to get Sauce Labs to report the names of the tests that are being run with CodeceptJS, but so far I've only been able to report success/failure.

I followed the following thread as a guide to help with reporting anything to Sauce Labs in general: https://github.com/Codeception/CodeceptJS/issues/371

The snippet I found is as follows:

```
_after() {
  if (process.env.SAUCE_USERNAME) {
    var sessionId = this.helpers['WebDriverIO'].browser.requestHandler.sessionID;
    var sauce_url = "Test finished. Link to job: https://saucelabs.com/jobs/";
    sauce_url = sauce_url.concat(sessionId);
    console.log(sauce_url);


    var dataString = '{"passed": true}';
    var status_url = 'https://saucelabs.com/rest/v1/';
    status_url = status_url.concat(process.env.SAUCE_USERNAME);
    status_url = status_url.concat('/jobs/');
    status_url = status_url.concat(sessionId);

    var options = {
      url: status_url,
      method: 'PUT',
      body: dataString,
      auth: {
        'user': process.env.SAUCE_USERNAME,
        'pass': process.env.SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY
      }
    };

    function callback(error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
      }
    }

    request(options, callback);
  }
}
```

The problem here is that I don't know how to access the test name from here, nor do I know how to obtain the status of the test (pass/fail).

I've since learned that with helpers you can dispatch events on test passed or test failed. I created a new file, made sure to add it in the hooks section of the config, and added the event dispatchers. This is great because now I have access to the test object, however the following code does not work:

```
event.dispatcher.on(event.test.failed, function(test, testError) {
  console.log("TEST FAILED...");
  console.log(this.helpers["WebDriverIO"]);
  var sessionId = this.helpers["WebDriverIO"].browser.requestHandler
    .sessionID;
  console.log(sessionId);
  var sauce_url = "Test finished. Link to job: https://saucelabs.com/jobs/";
  sauce_url = sauce_url.concat(sessionId);
  console.log(sauce_url);

  var dataString = `{"passed": false, "name": "${
    test.title
  }","customData": { "error": ${test.steps} }}`;
  var status_url = "https://saucelabs.com/rest/v1/";
  status_url = status_url.concat(process.env.CLOUDSERVICE_USERNAME);
  status_url = status_url.concat("/jobs/");
  status_url = status_url.concat(sessionId);

  var options = {
    url: status_url,
    method: "PUT",
    body: dataString,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.CLOUDSERVICE_USERNAME,
      pass: process.env.CLOUDSERVICE_KEY
    }
  };

  function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      console.log(body);
    }
  }

  request(options, callback);
});
```

The reason it doesn't work is because the following line does not seem to work:

```
var sessionId = this.helpers['WebDriverIO'].browser.requestHandler.sessionID;
```

Specifically, `this.helpers['WebDriverIO']` does not get printed out to my console, leading me to believe that it does not work from a helper context.

Is there some way to retrieve the session ID of a test from the context of an event dispatch? The documentation for tests seems to suggest that there are other properties but does not list them. Here's the doc for reference: https://codecept.io/hooks/#api

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can probably use the [saucelab](https://github.com/danjenkins/node-saucelabs)s package to handle this.

Set it up and auth first

```
const SauceLabs = require('saucelabs')

saucelabs = new SauceLabs({
  username: your-username,
  password: your-accessKey
});
```

And then once the test is complete you can post the results back to SauceLabs like so:

```
saucelabs.updateJob(sessionID, {
  name: test-title,
  passed: passed
}, done);
```