# How to override the test name given by wdio-sauce-service to SauceLabs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver-io, saucelabs

SauceLabs typically uses the last `describe()` test title to name the test in its archives. Unfortunately, with several layers of `describe`, this might result in not very meaningful names. Thus I would like to dynamically change the name of the test, e.g. using 
I've seen in different places, e.g. the [WebdriverIO Testrunner Configuration](http://webdriver.io/guide/getstarted/configuration.html#desiredCapabilities) doc that one should just update the `desiredCapabilities` like so

```
browser.desiredCapabilities.name = "my test name"
```

Setting this in a `beforeTest` or `afterTest` hook “works”, as in does not throw an error and is reflected in the `desiredCapabilities` object, but it is not used by SauceLabs as the name for the test run in the archive.

[Another answer here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49784141/3951916), given for a similar question with CodeceptJS suggests

```
const SauceLabs = require('saucelabs')

saucelabs = new SauceLabs({
  username: your-username,
  password: your-accessKey
});

// run test(s) ...

saucelabs.updateJob(sessionID, {
  name: test-title,
  passed: passed
}, done);
```

Unfortunately, I don't even have/need the SauceLabs module.

It seems the culprit is `wdio-sauce-service`, because the [WebdriverIO Using Cloud Services](http://webdriver.io/guide/usage/cloudservices.html#With-Travis-CI) doc states that

> if you set the `name`, this changes the name of this test in Sauce Labs for this build. If you are using the WDIO testrunner combined with the `wdio-sauce-service` WebdriverIO automatically sets a proper name for the test.

How do I override the name that `wdio-sauce-service` passes to SauceLabs?

Answer (score 1):

As of writing this, `wdio-sauce-service` has been replaced by `@wdio/sauce-service`, which also relies on the SauceLabs module you've referenced here. In both services, the final step to a Sauce Labs session updates the job in the `after()` function which triggers as the session is closing, or is already closed.

The only ways you can overwrite the job name are by modifying the service code, making your own, or doing an additional call to SauceLabs' API after the sauce-service does it using your framework functions, if your framework allows.

If you use the `name` capability, it will have a side-effect of making all tests having the same job name.